# When I set the ringermode to RINGER_MODE_SILENT, the phone still vibrates and the icon in the menu is set to the 'vibrate' icon

Tags: android

When I execute this code:

```
mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT );
```

the icon in my menubar on top is set to the vibrate icon and the vibrate setting is set to vibrate and not to silent.

What I expect from 'silent' is no-vibrate, no-sound.

It's on my phone on Android 4.4.4

Comment: What device are you testing on? At least in a Nexus 4 with 4.4.4 this code DOES set the proper "silent" mode (including icon).

Comment: you mean silent as in 'no sound' or realy as in 'no sound AND no vibrate' ?

Comment: Silent as in "no sound and no vibrate" (i.e. pressing "volume up" afterwards switches to vibrate mode). With Android 5.0 however it turns on Priority Mode instead. What phone are you testing on?

Comment: I'm running on a motorola moto G. If you are so confident it should work, I'll look again.

Comment: Well, it _does_ look like the correct way of doing it, and it works in the 4.4.4 device I have available. I can't affirm anything else apart from that, unfortunately. Good luck!

Comment: only working in nexux and samsung devices. In Moto not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio.setRingerMode(0);
```

Android Manifest file:

```
<application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
</application>
```

Comment: Isn't RINGER_MODE_SILENT equal to 0?

Comment: yes but it may be due to api changes it is needed constant value.
also check manifest file

Comment: if it still not work add one more permission of
Config changes

Comment: Concerning `android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` see my comment to @Tapa Save's answer

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>is only for system apps. and with other 2 permission, code is not working for moto devices

Answer (score 1):

```
 mAudioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

### [For more detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230388/android-ics-control-silent-mode-off-vibrate-or-mute/12238157#12238157)

Answer (score 0):

Try use this for silent mode:

```
getSystemService( Context.AUDIO_SERVICE).setRingerMode( AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

or normal mode:

```
getSystemService( Context.AUDIO_SERVICE).setRingerMode( AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```

Also permissions and uses-sdk (insode 'manifest' not 'application'):

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: No app outside of the system/firmware can get the `android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission. You can ask for it but what you get is a different story [see here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5034276/1986583)